# Mongoose update push, delete in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose model:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    loginName: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    hashedPassword: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    salt: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    rooms: [{ _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, loginName: [{ type: String }] }]
});
```

Example result:

```
{
    _id: "56c0a986eeb118741109a45f",
    loginName: "MegaDaddgy",
    hashedPassword: "*****",
    salt: "******",
    __v: 10,
    rooms: [
        {
            _id: "56c0a986eeb118741109a461",
            loginName: [
                "MegaDaddgy"
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: "56c0d9e332f6ddc80ec7271c",
            loginName: [
                "MegaDaddgy"
            ]
        }
    ],
    created: "2016-02-14T16:21:26.272Z"
}
```

What I need:

1. search on field : `rooms._id` in every user document,
2. push new loginName in array loginName in every found user document
3. delete selected loginName in array

Example params:

1. rooms._id : 56c0a986eeb118741109a461
2. loginName: "John"

Result:

```
{
    _id: "56c0a986eeb118741109a45f",
    loginName: "MegaDaddgy",
    hashedPassword: "*****",
    salt: "******",
    __v: 10,
    rooms: [
        {
            _id: "56c0a986eeb118741109a461",
            loginName: [
                "MegaDaddgy", "John"
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: "56c0d9e332f6ddc80ec7271c",
            loginName: [
                "MegaDaddgy"
            ]
        }
    ],
    created: "2016-02-14T16:21:26.272Z"
}
```

Example params:

1. rooms._id : 56c0a986eeb118741109a461
2. loginName: "John"

Result:

```
{
    _id: "56c0a986eeb118741109a45f",
    loginName: "MegaDaddgy",
    hashedPassword: "*****",
    salt: "******",
    __v: 10,
    rooms: [
        {
            _id: "56c0a986eeb118741109a461",
            loginName: [
                "MegaDaddgy"
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: "56c0d9e332f6ddc80ec7271c",
            loginName: [
                "MegaDaddgy"
            ]
        }
    ],
    created: "2016-02-14T16:21:26.272Z"
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could push `John` into `loginName` array through [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/push/)

```
Model.update({'rooms._id': ObjectId('56c0a986eeb118741109a461')}, 
    {$push: {'rooms.$.loginName': 'John'}}, function(...));
```

delete `John` from `loginName` array through [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

```
Model.update({'rooms._id': ObjectId('56c0a986eeb118741109a461')}, 
    {$pull: {'rooms.$.loginName': 'John'}}, function(...));
```